# Disable onChange event when DOM is changes via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

A page will display a range of time using one of the following two approaches:

1. Absolute Date Range. Two date fields (Bootstrap datepicker) representing the start and end of some duration of time.
2. Relative Date Range. Two text day fields (actually xeditor) where one represents the amount of days in the past and the other represents some duration of days.

Regardless of which approach is used, the two endpoints in some time range is defined.  A radio button is used to toggle which of the two approaches is displayed on the page, and when changed, the values of the newly displayed approach must be updated to match the one being hidden.

I also have an onChange event tied to all of them which is used to update the current state and whether the "Save Data" button is enabled.

My problem is if relative date range is currently displayed and the radio button is clicked, I calculate what the absolute dates should be and change the datepicker date values, but that in turn triggers the onChange event on them.

How can I change the value of the datepicker without triggering the onChange event?

Comment: why not just have code in the onChange method that determines if it should execute?

Comment: Make use of statements in your onchange event to see if you should execute a specific part or not. `if/else`, `switch/case` etc.

Comment: Thanks Rick and Martin,  That is what I am currently doing, but it seems ugly.  I have a global "disabled" variable which I set before changing their values.